# What is wrong with my Terraria character?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I play Terraria on a tablet and sometimes it gets laggy, usually when this happens I simply restart the tablet, But the last time I did this, my character got messed up. Instead of my character, It just shows the basic character and the name is a red question mark and it won't let me use it. How do I fix this?

[image: Select Player screen showing one character: default character design, default stats, 0 playtime, name is a red question mark]

Comment: Some photos would be helpful so we can see what it looks like. Are you using the most recent version of the game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The red question mark and 'default' character means that your character save is corrupted and no longer usable. Unless you've made backups elsewhere of your data this character is very likely lost for good if restarts havent brought them back.

Corrupted saves have a higher chance of happening when you exit the game forcefully while it is currently trying to save(that's why a lot of games have messaging along the lines of "if you see this icon don't turn off the game"). You mention you close the game when it gets laggy... being "laggy" could've actually meant it was busy doing the extra work of saving.

Comment: To complete the explanation: When you save a game, the first thing that is done is... delete the old save. So if you cut the game when it deleted the save file, but didnt write it yet, your savefile will be dead.